# Accessing methods from Jquery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Looking at the `onSelect` event that `Datepicker` has (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect), the second parameter is `obj inst` (an instance of the Datepicker).

I need to then call the `getDate()` method (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) and was wondering how I could do so using the passed `inst` object.

Note, I guess I could just call `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );` but it seems inefficient given the event already passes me an instance of the object I need.

Comment: Why you want to get the Date from instance?  you already have it in first parameter right?

Comment: A string representation yes, but I need it as type `Date`.